# Rails 3 - keep params after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to keep my params afterr i do submit.

In my Rails 3.2.0 application i have something like that:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/journals?class_code=11v&subject_name=Math
```

And i have form:

```
<%= form_for @lesson, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
    ....
    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to keep my params (`class_code` and `subject_name`) after `f.submit`. How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To store all parameters in one field, you could use:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :parameters, request.query_string  %>
```

And then you can access them in controller, using:

```
parameters = parse_nested_query(params[:parameters])
```

Comment: In Rails 4, you how have to specify `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query`

Answer (score 5):

hidden fields

```
  ....
  <%= hidden_field_tag :class_code, params[:class_code] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :subject_name, params[:subject_code] %>
  <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

but - if those are attributes of your model, then assign them in the new action of the controller

```
def new
  @lesson = Lesson.new(:class_code => params[:class_code], :subject_code => params[:subject_code])
end

# in this case the view code is slightly different
<%= f.hidden_field :class_code %>
<%= f.hidden_field :subject_code %>
```